# Valid update query was not executed in psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I have a update sql query which to be executed by psycopg2 but it seems that its not working or executed.

I debug the query to be executed using `mogrify` function.

```
req = cursor.mogrify(request_update_sql, (status, previous_status, request_id) )
```

which translates to:

```
b'UPDATE "TBL_COVER" SET status=\'cancelled\', previous_status=\'pending\', date_updated=current_timestamp WHERE cover_id=\'COVER_00008\''
```

The function that generates the update sql string:

```
def update_request_status(has_comments=False, has_approver_id=False):
    str_query = f"UPDATE \"TBL_COVER\" SET status=%s, previous_status=%s, date_updated=current_timestamp WHERE cover_id=%s"
    return str_query
```

that original code should be like below but I test simple update query to check the bug easier:

```
def update_request_status(has_comments=False, has_approver_id=False):
    str_query = f"UPDATE \"TBL_COVER\" SET status=%s, previous_status=%s, date_updated=current_timestamp"
    
    if has_comments:
        str_query += f", comments=%s"
    if has_approver_id:
        str_query += f", approver_id=%s"
        
    str_query += f" WHERE cover_id=%s"
        
    return str_query
```

After execution:
`cursor.execute(request_update_sql, (status, previous_status, cover_id) )`
I try to display the cursor content, it says `"DatabaseError: no results to fetch"`

Is there anything wrong that I miss?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: An `UPDATE` query does not return anything unless you use the `RETURNING` clause in the query. See [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Comment: The issue is, it does not update the selected record in the database.

Comment: Well in the code you posted I do not see anywhere where you commit the transaction, like `connection.commit()`. Without a commit the `UPDATE` will not persist past the session. If you want a complete answer you will  need to update your question to include a complete self contained example of what you are doing and where the error(s) is/are appearing.